# Moran's I and mixed effect model correlation error structure

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, spatial

When creating a mixed model with spatial data, you need to check that any model isn't being influenced by spatial autocorrelation. To my understanding, the most robust way of doing this is by calculating Moran's I of model residuals. I use the `spData` 'baltimore' dataset in this example, modelling house price as a response of number of rooms, with city council as a random effect.

```r
library(spData)
library(nlme)
library(ape)

baltimore<-spData::baltimore
baltimore$logpr = log(baltimore$PRICE)

model1 <- lme(logpr ~ NROOM  , random = ~1|CITCOU, 
               data = baltimore)
summary(model1)

dists <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(baltimore$X, baltimore$Y)))
dists.inv <- 1/dists
diag(dists.inv) <- 0
Moran.I(x = residuals(model1), weight = dists.inv)
```

Even though observed Moran's I is small, the significant P value is still a problem. The common response to addressing spatial autocorrelation of models is by defining correlation structure and including it in the model. The lowest AIC is usually how correlation structure is selected.

```r
model2 <- lme(logpr ~ NROOM  , random = ~1|CITCOU, 
              data = baltimore, 
               correlation = corRatio(form = ~ X + Y))
summary(model2)

Moran.I(x = residuals(model2), weight = dists.inv)
```

Why on earth has defining correlation structure INCREASED Moran's I? Shouldn't any specification of correlation structure bring the observed value closer to zero? I would expect even a slight reduction, but no.

UPDATE - the same thing happens when substituting the `residuals` call with `predict`

Comment: The output of residuals(model2) _includes_ the spatially correlated term, as this is considered 'error' in many mixed models. In temporal (growth) models or spatial analyses, this 'error' has a real interpretation, so that's why it might be confusing that it's part of the residuals. Note also that predict(model2) returns the fixed + random part, but not the spatially correlated (residual) part.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I understand your point, but then shouldn't the observed Moran's I be the same as before correlation structure is included? Moreover, how then can I measure if the correlation structure has reduced spatail autocorrelation if not through the residuals(model) call?

Comment: It might be slightly higher, as including it in the model will change some of the other estimated parameters. Part of the spatially correlated part was likely previously being consumed by your random intercepts. Not exactly sure, just a hunch.

Comment: Note that random intercepts are just AR1 processes with infinite range. A similar arugment can be made about random slopes. So, a similar problem as in multicollinearity occurs when fitting both effects on limited data. In prediction models, this is generally not an issue.